# WebSupergoo ABCPDF Automatic pdf generation - Adding pages on the fly?

Tags: c#, abcpdf

I have a question regarding building dynamic PDF documents with ABCPDF.dll.

I understand the basics and have a solid solution working. I have a new requirement where I need to dynamically add pages to a PDF doc.

Specifically, my PDF doc is a two pager. The second page needs to be a separate PDF file where one or more pages will be added by the user.

I've looked at the docs and code samples and see a AddPage() method. It doesn't seem liek this would work per my need.

Here is a code sample:

```
         void Page_Load( object sender, System.EventArgs e )
    {
        int theID = 0;
        string theText = "This PDF file is generated by WebSupergoo ABCpdf.NET on the fly";
        Doc theDoc = new Doc();

        theDoc.Width = 4;
        theDoc.FontSize = 32;
        theDoc.Rect.Inset( 20, 20 );
        theDoc.FrameRect();
        theID = theDoc.AddHtml( theText );

        while ( theDoc.GetInfo( theID, "Truncated" ) == "1" )
        {
            theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
            theDoc.FrameRect();
            theID = theDoc.AddHtml( "", theID );
        }
        theDoc.Save( Server.MapPath( "textflow.pdf" ) );
        theDoc.Clear();

        Response.Write( "PDF file written<br>" );
        Response.Write( "<a href=\"textflow.pdf\">View PDF File</a>" );
    }
```

Can someone suggest a method for adding pages to a PDF document using ABC PDF? The above sample may be using AddPage, but I need to specify another PDF file to dynamical add on the fly. The PDF file name can change.

Thank you.

Thank you.

Comment: I have code at work to do this using ABCPDF. We take loads of individual PDFs and join them to make one big document. I'm not at work now though! If you're still looking for a answer by tommorow, I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you want to add a PDF to the end of a different PDF. If that is what you need, it looks like the [Append method](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/append.htm) is what you need.

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. Exactly what I was looking for... thank you @G_P.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that abcpdf allows you to merge a PDF document to the end of another.  See [here](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/append.htm)